# How to get minimum and maximum individually and not as a whole?

Tags: java, max, min

Program does this:

Check if the max and min changes over the whole course of runs, and then prints them to the respective variables after each instance is complete based on user input.

But what I want it to do is:

Check the max and min for each individual run, then print them to the respective variables.

How can I change the code below so that it gets the max and min of each run instead of the overall max and min?

Here is the code:

```
package test;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random generator = new Random();
        float smallest, largest;
         int years;
         float[] array = new float[12];

         smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter desired years: ");
years = keyboard.nextInt();

for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++){
    System.out.println("Year " + i);
    for (int month = 1; month <= array.length; month++){
    array[i] = generator.nextFloat() * 100;
    System.out.println("Month " + month + ": " + array[i]);
    if(array[i] < smallest) 
        smallest = array[i];
    if(array[i] > largest) 
        largest = array[i];

}
    System.out.println("Max = " + largest);
    System.out.println("Min = " + smallest);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do both? I've modified my code to do the individual runs for each years, and now I am trying to do both an overall max, min, mean, median and mode and one for the individual runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't resetting largest and smallest at the end of the loop.

```
package test;

import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random generator = new Random();
        float smallest, largest;
        int years;
        float[] array = new float[12];

        smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter desired years: ");
        years = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
            System.out.println("Year " + i);
            for (int month = 1; month <= array.length; month++) {
                array[i] = generator.nextFloat() * 100;
                System.out.println("Month " + month + ": " + array[i]);
                if (array[i] < smallest)
                    smallest = array[i];
                if (array[i] > largest)
                    largest = array[i];

            }
            System.out.println("Max = " + largest);
            System.out.println("Min = " + smallest);

            // HERE
            // Reset largest and smallest
            largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! I didn't know that you could do that.